# How to Implement accessibilityCustomActions for VoiceOver on Mac?

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, voiceover

I have a button that responds to various mouse clicks (regular click, right click, control+click, option+click, command+click...) to show different popup menus. Since it would be annoying for VoiceOver users to use actual physical mouse, I would like to map those to different VoiceOver actions.

However, I'm not getting the results I expected. Could someone help me to understand better what I'm missing? Here is what I discovered so far.

If I subclass `NSButton` and override the following functions, they work fine. Except there's one odd thing. If I press vo+command+space to bring up the list of available actions, VoiceOver says Action 1 instead of Show Menu.

```
override func accessibilityPerformPress() -> Bool { 
    print("Pressed!") 
    return true 
}

override func accessibilityPerformShowAlternateUI() -> Bool { 
    print("Show Alternate UI") 
    return true 
} 

override func accessibilityPerformShowMenu() -> Bool { 
    print("Show Menu") 
    return true 
}
```

In the same `NSButton` subclass, if I also override `accessibilityCustomActions` function, "Do Something" never comes up in the list of available actions when I press vo+command+space.

```
override func accessibilityCustomActions() -> [NSAccessibilityCustomAction]? { 
    let custom = NSAccessibilityCustomAction(name: "Do Something", target: self, selector: #selector(doSomething)) 
    return [custom] 
} 

@objc func doSomething() -> Bool { 
    print("Done something.") 
    return true 
}
```

If I subclass `NSView` instead of `NSButton`, and override the same functions from #1, everything works fine. Unlike first case, even VoiceOver correctly says "Show Menu" for the action from `accessibilityPerformShowMenu` instead of "Action 1".

in the same `NSView` subclass, if I override `accessibilityCustomActions` along with `accessibilityPerformPress`, `accessibilityPerformShowMenu`, or `accessibilityPerformShowAlternateUI`, "Do Something" doesn't come up in the action list.

However, "Do Something" does come up in the action list if I just override `accessibilityCustomActions` by itself without `accessibilityPerformPress`, `accessibilityPerformShowMenu`, and `accessibilityPerformShowAlternateUI`.

I tried creating another action with the name "Press" that does the same thing when pressing vo+space, and including in the return value of `accessibilityCustomActions`. However, Vo+space did not trigger the action. Instead, I had to press vo+command+space, and then select "Press". I guess the action just has the name "Press", but it's not actually connected to vo+space. I'm not sure how I can actually make that particular custom action to respond to vo+space.

I would appreciate if someone could help me to implement `accessibilityCustomActions` as well as `accessibilityPerformPress`, `accessibilityPerformShowMenu`, and `accessibilityPerformShowAlternateUI` together into `NSButton`.

Thanks so much!

Comment: If a single button responds differently to five (or more?) different types of clicks, doesn't this result in very bad usability? How would a user remember which click results in which response? How do you plan to communicate this different interaction methods, both to sighted users and to screenreader users?

Comment: I see your point for User Experience, but it's beyond my control. This is an extremely complex media editing software, and it has hundreds of keyboard and mouse shortcuts. Simply because of just sheer numbers of features, users have been memorizing them as part of their workflows for a long time. If you've used something like Final Cut Pro or Logic Pro, you'd understand why something like this might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overriding these AX methods on the `NSButton`, not the `NSButtonCell`. For nearly everything to do with accessibility in `NSControl`s, you will want to deal with the `NSCell` in question. If you use the custom action code you've written above and stick it in a subclass of `NSButtonCell` used by your button, then it will work.